# JQuery- Make a Post Request with Authorization

Tags: c#, jquery, post, blogger

I have been trying to figure out way to Post json data using Blogger API 3.0. I do have a idea about GET method so I am able to hit a url an read json data but I am a bit confused about how exactly i can make following request

```
Adding a post

You can add a post for a blog by sending a POST request to the post collection URI with a post JSON body:

POST https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/8070105920543249955/posts/
Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "kind": "blogger#post",
  "blog": {
    "id": "8070105920543249955"
  },
  "title": "A new post",
  "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."
}
You must be authenticated to create a post.
```

I have bee trying to use Blogger API 3 which allows to create new post.

ref: http://code.blogger.com/2012/06/blogger-api-v3.html

**Update:** I am a bit curious if same thing can be done using Console Application using C# as Programming language.

Answer (score 0):

To send post request:

```
var post_data = {
   "kind": "blogger#post",
   "blog": {"id": "8070105920543249955"},
   "title": "A new post",
   "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'your_request_url_here',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: post_data,
    complete: function(res) {
       console.log(res);
    }
})
```

Comment: How do we pass the `Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */`?